# How do you whitelist an IP address with just one line command?

Tags: networking, firewall

I've been searching how to whitelist a IP address (ex. 123.123.321.1) with Ubuntu 12.04. But everyone seems to give long elaborate answers. Is there just 1 simple command to whitelist an IP address? I want to whitelist an IP address so it can connect via SSH port 22. Also would this solution work with other linux flavors like centos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo ufw allow in from 123.123.321.1 to any port 22
```

CentOS doesn't use ufw. You'll have to use `iptables`.

Comment: thanks! do you have to flush or reload something after you do that? it doesnt seem to work after using that command. i do see my ip address loaded when i do a ufw status.

Comment: @duckx oh, yeah. `sudo ufw enable && sudo ufw reload`.

Comment: still doesn't work. what could i be missing? http://prntscr.com/a99i4k

Comment: @duckx You asked how to add a rule. That's how you add the rule. If you're trying to do something more specific than you will have to be much more detailed.

Comment: im just trying to SSH to my box thats all. not sure why its not working with your solution. thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @duckx Are you behind a NAT router? If so, did you set up port forwarding? What errors are you getting? Answers to those questions are what you should be including in your next question.

Comment: i'm not behind any router. its a vps from digital ocean. turning off the ufw, it works fine, but i'm not sure why these rules arent working.